# How to hide and show features in OpenLayers 3? (Redraw?)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm updating a project from [OL2](https://openlayers.org/two/) to [OL3](https://openlayers.org/), but I'm stuck on how to redraw features after changing the feature style.

In OL2, this worked:

```
hidePoints: function(id) {
    if (! this.getMap().center) {
        return;
    }

    var i,
    feature,    
    len = this.points.features.length;

   if (id !== null) {
    for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {         
      feature = this.points.features[i];
      if (feature.attributes.aces_id == id) {
          feature.style = null;
        } else {
            feature.style = { display: 'none' };
        }
      }
   } else {
      for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {         
        feature = this.points.features[i];
        feature.style = { display: 'none' };
      }
   }
 this.points.redraw();
},
```

In OL3, I tried updating the function to hide the points layer, but `redraw()` no longer exists and since the layer I am working with is an `ol.layer.Vector`, I can't find any `updateParams` options like other sources besides vectors have. Dispatch Event and changed also did not work. I was hoping changed would, but nothing happens.

```
hidePoints: function(id) {
    if (! this.getMap().getView().getCenter()) {
        return;
    }

    var i,
        feature,
        layerSourceFeatures = this.pointsLayer.getSource().getFeatures(),
        len = layerSourceFeatures.length;

    if (id !== null) {
        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            feature = this.pointsLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[i];

            if (feature.get('aces_id') == id) {
                feature.style = null;
            } else {
                feature.style = { display: 'none' };
            }
        }
    } else {
        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            feature = this.pointsLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[i];
            feature.style = { display: 'none' };
        }
    }
    //this.pointsLayer.redraw();
    //this.pointsLayer.dispatchEvent(goog.events.EventType.CHANGE);
    this.pointsLayer.changed();
},
```

I'm also wondering if changing the style is done this way (fetching each feature to another var) or if that won't just change that feature and leave the original untouched. Plus always fetching `getSource().getFeatures()` seems abusive on the performance... but I can't seem to find another way.

Regardless, how is redraw performed in OL3 now to render features whose styles have been altered? A layer can be set as visible, but I don't want to hide/show all the features all the time. Sometimes I just want to hide/show a few according to their given id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So while looking at the documentation over and over, I finally found what would fire the change event, much like seto suggested after.

This is the converted function from OL2 to OL3 that works for me. Redraw is no longer needed since setStyle does it all.

```
hidePoints: function(id) {
    if (! this.getMap().getView().getCenter()) {
        return;
    }

    var i,
        feature,
        layerSourceFeatures = this.pointsLayer.getSource().getFeatures(),
        len = layerSourceFeatures.length;

    var emptyImgStyle = new ol.style.Style({ image: '' });

    // If an aces id was provided
    if (id !== undefined) {
        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            feature = layerSourceFeatures[i];

            feature.setStyle(emptyImgStyle);

            // Resetting feature style back to default function given in defaultPointStyleFunction()
            if (feature.get('aces_id') == id) {
                feature.setStyle(null);
            }
            // Hiding marker by removing its associated image
            else {
                feature.setStyle(emptyImgStyle);
            }
        }
    }
    // No id was provided - all points are hidden
    else {
        for( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            feature = layerSourceFeatures[i];
            feature.setStyle(emptyImgStyle);
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do it is using a style function and a hidden propertie on the feature:

```
var style = new ol.Style(...);

function Stylefunction (feature, resolution) {
    var prop = feature.getProperties();
    if (prop.HIDDEN)
       return;

    return style;
}

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(...),
    style: Stylefunction 
});
```

if you change the feature "HIDDEN" propertie, it instant refreshes

Comment: This seems like a cleaner approach to me.

Comment: @David could you expand on that? HIDDEN is an arbitrary chosen property, not something defined on OL3, right?

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments because I don't have enough reputation, but instead of `feature.style = null` you might want to call `feature.setStyle(null)`,  because this internally triggers the changed event and should instantaneously and automatically change the style. Also `feature.style = { display: 'none' }` will not work in openlayers 3 because the style needs to be an ol.style.Style object (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setStyle)

If you have the ID of the features, you can use the source.getFeatureById() method instead of cycling through the features.(http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeatureById)

Regards rendering, I think using the map's map.render() (at openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/apidoc/ol.Map.html#render) will re-render the map.

If you just to call a function whenever the map is re-rendered, you can listen on the postrender or postcompose events on the map.

If you create a JSFiddle, I can help you further.

Edit: This example might help you - openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/dynamic-data.html?q=style

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I ended up with a solution I liked yesterday through the setStyle you mentioned also. The id of the feature wouldn't help since they're hidden/shown according to an id in their values config.
I didn't know about the render or that example, thanks! :D
Though I'm not quite sure how to show the solution I achieved here though, guess I can answer it myself?

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach for layer toggling (applies to other features, as well):

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    var layerBing = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
              imagerySet: 'Aerial',
              key: 'YourKeyBingAccess'
          }),
          name: 'Bing'
    });

    /*
    *  YOUR MAP CODE  GOES HERE
    */

    function toggleLayer(layerObject) {
        var newVisibility = !(layerObject.get('visible'));
        layerObject.set('visible', newVisibility);
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="toggleLayer(layerBing)">Bing Satellite</button>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```