# Two markers at the same position

Tags: openlayers-3

2 markers at the same position how not display the tooltip of the hidden marker? When I pass over the visible markers.

```
    map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (layer == layer_1) {
            return feature;
        }
    });     

    map.getTarget().style.cursor = feature ? 'pointer' : '';                        
    tooltip.style.display = feature ? '' : 'none';                              
    if (feature){
        overlay.setPosition(e.coordinate);
        tooltip.innerHTML = 'marker hidden';            
    }

  });
```

[image: Hidden marker]

Comment: Please clarify you question, I'm unable to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: [link](http://www.mides.fr/geocaching/fullmapmerimetls/)

Comment: When I markers that are stacked events are triggered for all markeurs present in the area of the click. Not only for the first. it's the same problem with two various stacked layers. (click and hover) [example](http://www.mides.fr/geocaching/fullmapmerimetls/) – Mides 9 mins ago

Comment: May be an early solution but the code does not look good. :-( If you have ideas.

Comment: I still don't understand your issue. Please describe the desired behavior.

Comment: Look at code you will understand where is the problem with two  vector layer and event.  

[map] (http://www.mides.fr/geocaching/fullmapmerimetls/)

map.on('singleclick', function(evt).....

map.on('pointermove', function(evt)...

Answer (score 0):

Can't just comment or I would since I only want to ask you: did you try using setStyle() instead to change the style? That usually forces the change event. I'm asking that because I had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139170/how-to-hide-and-show-features-in-open-layers-3-redraw) to hide/show features.